# Make offer to opensea asset on polygon chain using opensea API

Tags: web3js, polygon, opensea, external-api

I have written this code using opensea API (not SDK) so far but it returns a 400 Bad Request error:

```
const sdk = require("api")("@opensea/v2.0#xx4df2gljerlft1");
const web3 = require("web3");
// const ethers = require("ethers");
const BN = require("bn.js");
const {
  signTypedData,
  SignTypedDataVersion,
} = require("@metamask/eth-sig-util");
sdk.auth("<opensea API key>");
PRIVATE_KEY =
  "<priv key>";

// Convert salt to BigNumber:
const bytesToUint = async (bytes32) => {
  bytes32str = bytes32.replace(/^0x/, "");
  let bn = new BN(bytes32str, 16).fromTwos(256);
  let result = bn.toString();
  return result;
};

// Breakdown considerations:
const considerationArray = async (arr) => {
  let additionalConsiderations = [];
  // console.log(arr);
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let item = {};
    item.amount = arr[i].endAmount;
    item.recipient = arr[i].recipient;
    additionalConsiderations.push(item);
  }
  return additionalConsiderations;
};

const getOrder = async (contract, id) => {
  const { data } = await sdk.retrieveListings({
    asset_contract_address: contract,
    token_ids: id,
    order_by: "created_date",
    order_direction: "desc",
    chain: "matic",
  });

  const order = data.orders[0];
  if (order == undefined || order == null) {
    throw new Error("No order found. Consider using a different token ID");
    return;
  }
  const buyOrderParams = order.protocol_data.parameters;
  const buySalt = await bytesToUint(buyOrderParams.salt);
  const buyConsiderations = await considerationArray(
    buyOrderParams.consideration
  );
  const buyData = {
    considerationToken: buyOrderParams.consideration[0].token,
    considerationIdentifier:
      buyOrderParams.consideration[0].identifierOrCriteria,
    considerationAmount: buyOrderParams.consideration[0].endAmount,
    offerer: web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(buyOrderParams.offerer),
    zone: buyOrderParams.zone,
    offerToken: buyOrderParams.offer[0].token,
    offerIdentifier: buyOrderParams.offer[0].identifierOrCriteria,
    offerAmount: buyOrderParams.offer[0].endAmount,
    basicOrderType: `${buyOrderParams.orderType}`,
    startTime: buyOrderParams.startTime,
    endTime: buyOrderParams.endTime,
    zoneHash: buyOrderParams.zoneHash,
    salt: buySalt,
    offererConduitKey: buyOrderParams.conduitKey,
    fulfillerConduitKey: buyOrderParams.conduitKey,
    totalOriginalAdditionalRecipients: `${
      buyOrderParams.consideration.length - 1
    }`,
    additionalRecipients: buyConsiderations,
  };
  const value = order.current_price;
  let orderData = {};
  orderData["data"] = buyData;
  orderData["value"] = value;
  console.log(orderData);
  return {
    orderDetails: orderData.data,
    orderData: data.orders[0].protocol_data.parameters,
  };
};

const fulfillOrder = async (message, orderData) => {
  const domain = {
    name: "OpenSea",
    version: "1.5",
    chainId: "137",
    verifyingContract: "0x00000000000000ADc04C56Bf30aC9d3c0aAF14dC",
  };
  const types = {
    EIP712Domain: [
      { name: "name", type: "string" },
      { name: "version", type: "string" },
      { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" },
    ],
    BasicOrderParameters: [
      { name: "considerationToken", type: "address" },
      { name: "considerationIdentifier", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "considerationAmount", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "offerer", type: "address" },
      { name: "zone", type: "bytes32" },
      { name: "offerToken", type: "address" },
      { name: "offerIdentifier", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "offerAmount", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "basicOrderType", type: "uint8" },
      { name: "startTime", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "endTime", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "zoneHash", type: "bytes32" },
      { name: "salt", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "offererConduitKey", type: "bytes32" },
      { name: "fulfillerConduitKey", type: "bytes32" },
      { name: "totalOriginalAdditionalRecipients", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "additionalRecipients", type: "AdditionalRecipient[]" },
    ],
    AdditionalRecipient: [
      { name: "amount", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "recipient", type: "address" },
    ],
  };
  const primaryType = "BasicOrderParameters";
  const signature = signTypedData({
    privateKey: PRIVATE_KEY,
    data: {
      types: types,
      primaryType: primaryType,
      domain: domain,
      message: message,
    },
    version: SignTypedDataVersion.V4,
  });
  // console.log(signature);

  sdk
    .createAnOffer(
      {
        protocol_address: "0x00000000000000ADc04C56Bf30aC9d3c0aAF14dC",
        signature: signature,
        parameters: orderData,
      },
      { chain: "matic" }
    )
    .then(({ data }) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};

const main = async () => {
  try {
    const { orderDetails, orderData } = await getOrder(
      (contract = "0xdb46d1dc155634fbc732f92e853b10b288ad5a1d"),
      (id = "95286")
    );
    console.log(orderData);
    fulfillOrder(orderDetails, orderData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

main();
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
  status: 400,
  data: {
    errors: [
      'You have attempted to create an offer, but the offer item is not a currency'
    ]
  },
```